# How do you deploy a .war file to a deep path in jboss?

Tags: java, servlets, javabeans

I have a project containing a .jsp that uses a JavaBean, but does not use a servlet.  I am trying to deploy it to servername:8080/path/projectname.  Unfortunately I can only figure out how to deploy it to servername:8080/projectname.  I have tried both editing my web.xml file to /path/projectname, and physically creating directory .../deploy/path with /projectname in my web.xml file.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can deploy a project to a particular path?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I've packed up several WAR files but never deployed one! They are only compressed archives, can't you uncompress it (with Winrar or similar) and just copy the files to the appropriate path?

Comment: How does one map the server to that location?  My .war file is already in .../deploy/path/ but the server is not mapping it properly when I try it from my browser.

Answer (score 0):

The WAR specification does not contain a standard way to tell the web container which URL a WAR file maps to, except the Tomcat convention that foo.war maps to /foo.  You need to have the WAR inside an EAR as the EAR can do that.

Hence you need a web container specific solution.  For JBoss it appears to be having the following in jboss-web.xml

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>...</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

I have not tried with JBoss so I cannot say if it can deep deploy.  See the documentation at http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/webguide/r2/en/html/ch06.html.